# Tag proposal: [self-scoring]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, scoring

I'd like to propose [self-scoring](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-scoring) or a similar tag, but I'd like to get some feedback on whether this is useful and how the tag might work.

First the proposal:

> [self-scoring](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-scoring) is a scoring criterion where the scoring mechanism and the task required are the same.  This means that if you pass your program to itself as input it should give you it's score.

Some examples are given at the bottom of the post.

My motivation for proposing the tag is that it would break of a (small) chunk of the many challenges with [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) into a more specific, searchable group.  [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) is never going away but it is not a very useful tag and it would be nice to split off developing groups if possible.

I do think this tag also has potential for a good deal more challenges to be made.  It's quite flexible and new challenges can be very innovative or novel.  It might be a little tough to come up with a *good* task that makes for an interesting scoring criterion, but I don't think we have exhausted the supply.

Now there are some things I think are worth discussing:

1. In finding examples I was not able to find a good example question that was asked by anyone other than myself.  It's possible this is just a personal fixation of mine and that other people are just not asking these.  Although it's possible that making this a tag could lead to interest from others, sparking new and innovative challenges.
2. The scoring can be pretty varied between challenges that meet the requirements.  It might be wrong to think of this as a *scoring criterion* tag.  Maybe it is better to think of the scoring criterion being [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) and the *task* being to implement whatever scoring criterion.
3. A similar type of challenge that doesn't fall under this is [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)+[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) challenges where you are required to *validate* rather than score your own program.  This challenge type even has some that *aren't asked by me!* Should we add [self-validating](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-validating) or something as well?  Should these just be one tag with a name that encompasses both of them?

### Examples:

Definite examples:

[1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/242034/),
[2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/233916/),
[3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/173586/),
[4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/172146/),
[5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127261/unique-is-cheap)

Marginal or possible examples:

[1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/171168/)

[self-validating](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-validating) examples:

[1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/201009/),
[2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/179422/),
[3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/174065/),
[4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/156967/),
[5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/171122/),
[6](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/167924/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Let's make both [self-scoring](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-scoring) and [self-validating](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-validating)

### [self-scoring](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-scoring) as a scoring criterion tag

The description of [self-scoring](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-scoring) as proposed is IMO well-defined enough to be a scoring criterion tag on its own, and I agree that there is a good potential for more interesting challenges of this type.

As a refinement tag for [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), I think it's better to keep it focused. So your "marginal example 1" doesn't fall into [self-scoring](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-scoring): each submission does output the score, but it doesn't take itself as input to produce the score, so it is not *self-scoring* by definition. (Similarly to "Output your score" challenges, IMO it's better classified as [self-referential](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-referential) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) as it already is.)

### [self-validating](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-validating) as a non-scoring criterion tag

[self-validating](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-validating) is a nice tag candidate too for reasons OP mentioned, but naturally it is a *validity criterion* tag rather than *scoring criterion*. I think it can replace [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) for the challenges mentioned ([decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) should stay IMO).

Also, since [self-scoring](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-scoring) would be a scoring criterion and [self-validating](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-validating) wouldn't, merging the two doesn't quite make sense.